# if clauses not working in laravel 5.3 mailable

Tags: email, phpmailer, laravel-5.3

in Laravel 5.1 I sent message like this. So user could send message with or without attachment.

```
                Mail::send('emails.contacts', $mailarray, function($message) use ($mailarray) {
                    $message->from($mailarray['email'], $mailarray['name'] );
                    $message->to('admin@site.ru', 'admin');
                    $message->setCc($mailarray['email'], $mailarray['name']);
                    $message->replyTo($mailarray['email'], $mailarray['name'] );
                    $message->subject('Письмо со страницы Контакты');

                    if ( isset($mailarray['attachment']) ) 
                    {
                        $message->attach($mailarray['attachment']->getRealPath(), array(
                            'as'    => $mailarray['attachment']->getClientOriginalName(), 
                            'mime'  => $mailarray['attachment']->getMimeType()));
                    }
                });
```

This approach is not working with Mailable. Doing this I get error

```
syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)
```

And it is working only like this, which is duplicating code a lot.

```
public function build()
{
    if (is_null($this->file) )  {
        return $this->subject('Обратный звонок с сайта')
                    ->view('emails.callback')
                    ->cc($this->input['email'], $this->input['name'])
                    ->replyTo($this->input['email'], $this->input['name']);
    }
    else {
        return $this->subject('Обратный звонок с сайта')
                    ->view('emails.callback')
                    ->cc($this->input['email'], $this->input['name'])
                    ->replyTo($this->input['email'], $this->input['name'])
                    ->attach($this->file, array('as' => $this->file->getClientOriginalName(), 'mime' => $this->file->getClientMimeType() ));
    }
}
```